# Conjugation for historical, legal, and literary texts?

Tags: españa, conjugación, español-neutral, conjunciones, lenguaje-jurídico

I was using an online verb [conjugator](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/comer), and I can see that some conjugations are reserved for `historical, legal, and literary texts`. At the moment, my Spanish is too basic to have come across these in my elementary level books.

I am trying to imagine some examples where I would use those conjugations, and I was hoping the community could give me some easy demonstrations. Perhaps if one day I have my own island in the sea, I could use the **future subjunctive** to write laws for StackExchange Island?

This question is just for Spanish spoken in Spain.

Comment: Where does it say that about legal etc. texts? I don't see it.

Comment: @Lambie The website is slightly different on a phone/tablet. On a computer, scroll down to the second bold heading Subjunctive, then hover the mouse cursor over the bold future text. A small popup bubble will appear, saying legal etc... texts.

Answer (score 1):

Versión en Español / Versión en Inglés

Spanish version / English version

---

### Versión en Español

El lenguaje jurídico es por lo general complicado para aquellas personas que no están habituados a él, ya que la misma interpretación de la ley, que corresponde a los jueces, o  la de las mismas sentencias, puede llevar a equívocos.

Como características generales en un tema tan amplio, destacamos;

**1 -** **La omisión injustificada del artículo.**

Ejemplos:

“*se le remite facturación de las mercancías*” / “*se le remite (la) facturación de las mercancías*”

“*para cumplir sanción de suspensión*” / “*para cumplir (la) sanción de suspensión*”

“*se acompaña original de Sentencia*” / “*se acompaña original de (la) Sentencia*”

**2 -** **Se hace un uso incorrecto del gerundio con función adjetiva.** (Reemplaza a un relativo + presente de indicativo o subjuntivo).

“*decreto disponiendo*” (*decreto que dispone*).

“*sentencia desestimando la falta de autorización*” (*sentencia que desestima la falta de autorización*).

“*instancia solicitando*” (*instancia que solicita*).

**3 -** **Algunos aspectos del uso del Subjuntivo** (Con acciones tenidas como dudosas o irreales y acciones tenidas como necesarias o deseadas.)

Su utilización lleva a veces a una incoherencia  y una mezcla de los tiempos.

Ejemplos:

"Cuando la muerte de un litigante conste al tribunal y no se **personare** el sucesor..." **Futuro de subjuntivo**

**Se conserva el futuro de subjuntivo** (**“amare”**), desaparecido de lengua estándar.

Acción hipotética considerada no acabada en el momento presente o en el futuro ( **“si así lo **hiciere**”, “si no se **abonare**”**) **Futuro de subjuntivo**

**Futuro perfecto de subjuntivo ("hubiere incurrido", “hubiere amado”**...), posibilidad en el pasado.

"... *procederá a la reclamación de la deuda aplazada y no pagada, así como a los intereses devengados y recargos en que se **hubiere incurrido***..." (**Futuro Perfecto de Subjuntivo**)

/ Utilizado de forma arcaica (el empleo de partes de frases hechas).

“*si procediere*” **Futuro de subjuntivo**

“*si hubiere lugar*” **Futuro de subjuntivo**

“*cuando estimare oportuno*” **Futuro de subjuntivo**

“*si no comparecieren*” **Futuro de subjuntivo**

"*El que matare a otro..*" **Futuro de subjuntivo**

"*El que causare daño a.*." **Futuro de subjuntivo**

/ Con el deseo de expresar matices ( normalmente en la redacción de las leyes).

/ Determina la elegancia expositiva y precisión conceptual.

/ Mantiene un tono exhortativo e imperativo (obligación).

**4 - El uso de la figura del "anacoluto"** que consiste en la ruptura de la estructura de la oración, la omisión de las reglas de concordancia y la subordinación:

“*Se requiere al Sr. Pons para que dirija al Gobernador Civil un nuevo escrito y haciendo constar los datos y cada uno de los extremos que aparecen*”.

5 - **Utilización del Hipérbaton**, que es una inversión del orden normal de palabras.

Ejemplo:

“*Salvo  recurso contra providencias del artículo 420, resuelto en el mismo artículo según dicho precepto legal, aquellos  incidentes, excepciones y reposiciones que pudieran plantearse en
juicios atribuidos a esta Ley especial, remitirán en su defecto al Juez de primera instancia que resolverá por sentencia sobre la cuestión principal*”.

Por :

“*Aquellos  incidentes, excepciones y reposiciones que pudieran plantearse en juicios atribuidos a esta Ley especial, remitirán en su defecto al Juez de primera instancia que resolverá por sentencia sobre la cuestión principal, salvo  recurso contra providencias del artículo 420, resuelto en el mismo artículo según dicho precepto legal.* ”.

**6 - Construcción de oraciones sin verbo principal**, que se sustituye por un **infinitivo**: "Para comenzar, **comentar** que el...*"

**7 - En algunas frases, el participio funciona como adjetivo**.

"*El abogado, **cansado** del juicio, desapareció sin dar explicación*"

Algunos verbos tienen **dos formas de participio**:
*soltado/suelto - imprimido/impreso - confundido/confuso*.

**8 - Lo que llamamos Cláusulas absolutas**.

Ejemplos:

“presentada la demanda”

“*visto el expediente*”

“*leídas las declaraciones*”

“*transcurrido el plazo*”

**9 - Uso arcaico del participio de presente del latín**:

Ejemplos:

“*de los antecedentes obrantes se desprende.*..”

“*el abajo firmante*”

“*firma del declarante*”.

**10 - Participio de pasado + “que” + verbo.**

Ejemplo:

"*transcurridos que sean*"

**11 - Utilización y abuso del "queísmo"**.

Omisión de la conjunción "que", admitido por la RAE pero desaconsejable.

Ejemplos:

“*le ruego conteste con brevedad” - “le ruego (**que**) conteste con brevedad*”

“*solicita sea revisado*” - “*solicita (**que**) sea revisado*”.

“*he acordado se proceda a la apertura de expediente*” - “ *acordado (**que**) se proceda a la apertura de expediente*”..

“*desea se le tenga en cuenta” - “desea (**que**) se le tenga en cuenta*”

**12 - Ausencia y abuso de Concordancia**

Entre sujeto y verbo
Entre Pronombres
En construcciones con participios
Entre nombre y adjetivo
Entre sustantivo y relativo
Entre artículo y nombre

En general estos son algunos ejemplos del lenguaje jurídico y de su utilización.

---

---

### English version

Legal language is generally complicated for those who are not used to it, since the same interpretation of the law, which corresponds to the judges, or that of the sentences themselves, can lead to misunderstandings.

As general characteristics in such a broad topic, we highlight;

**1 - The unjustified omission of the article.**

Examples:

“*invoicing for the goods is sent to you” / se le remite (**la**) facturación de las mercancías

“*to comply with the suspension sanction” / “para cumplir (**la**) sanción de suspensión”

“*The original of the Judgment is attached” / “se acompaña original de (**la**) Sentencia”

**2 - Incorrect use of the gerund with function adjective** (Replaces a relative + present indicative or subjunctive).

"*decreto disposing".

"decreto disponiendo (gerund)*” (**decreto que dispone**)

“*Sentence dismissing (**gerund**) the lack of authorization” (sentence **that dismisses** the lack of authorization)*.

"sentencia **desestimando (gerund)** la falta de autorización*” (sentencia **que desestima** la falta de autorización)

“*instance requesting (gerund)”*. "instancia **solicitando (gerund)***” (*instancia **que solicita**)

**3 - Some aspects of the use of the Subjunctive** (With actions considered doubtful or unreal and actions considered necessary or desired.)

Its use sometimes leads to an inconsistency and a mixture of times.

Examples:

"*When the death of a litigant is recorded in court and the successor does not appear*..." **Future Subjunctive**

"Cuando la muerte de un litigante conste al tribunal y no se **personare** el sucesor..." **Futuro de subjuntivo** **Future Subjunctive**

The **future subjunctive** ("amare") is preserved, disappeared from the standard language. Hypothetical action considered not finished in the present moment or in the future ("*if I do so", "if not will be paid*”)

---

**Futuro de subjuntivo**

**Futuro perfecto de subjuntivo ("hubiere incurrido", “hubiere amado”**...), posibilidad en el pasado.

Future perfect subjunctive ("*would have incurred*", "*would have loved"...*), possibility in the past.

"...*will proceed to claim the deferred and unpaid debt, as well as accrued interest and surcharges incurred*..."

**Future Perfect Subjunctive**

"... *procederá a la reclamación de la deuda aplazada y no pagada, así como a los intereses devengados y recargos en que se **hubiere incurrido***..." (**Futuro Perfecto de Subjuntivo**) (**Future Perfect Subjunctive**)

/ Used in an archaic way (the use of parts of set phrases).

“if applicable” * “*si **procediere***” *Future Subjunctive**

“if there is room” “*si **hubiere** lugar*” **Future Subjunctive**

“*when deemed appropriate*” “*cuando **estimare** oportuno*” **Future Subjunctive**

"*if they don't show up*"  “*si no **comparecieren***” **Future Subjunctive**

"*Whoever kills another*..." "*El que **matare** a otro..*" **Future Subjunctive**

"*Whoever harms*..." "*El que causare daño a...*." **Future Subjunctive**

/ With the desire to express nuances (usually in the drafting of laws).

/ Determines expository elegance and conceptual precision.

/ It maintains an exhortative and imperative tone (obligation).

**4 - The use of the figure of the "anacoluto"** that consists of the rupture of the structure of the sentence, the omission of the concordance rules and the subordination:

"*Mr. Pons is required to address a new letter to the Civil Governor and stating the data and each of the extremes that appear*."

**5 - Use of the Hyperbaton**, which is an inversion of the normal order of words

Example:

“***Except for appeal** against provisions of article 420, resolved in the same article according to said legal precept, **those incidents**, exceptions and replacements that could arise in trials attributed to this special Law, will refer, failing that, to the Judge of first instance who will resolve by sentence on the main issue*.

By :

“***Those incidents**, exceptions and repositions that could arise in trials attributed to this special Law, will refer, failing that, to the Judge of first instance who will resolve by sentence on the main issue, **except for appeal** against provisions of article 420, resolved in the same article according to said legal precept*. ”.

**6 - Construction of sentences without a main verb**, which is replaced by an infinitive: "To begin, **comment** that the..."

"Para comenzar, **comentar** que el...*" "**Infinitive**"

**7 - In some sentences, the participle functions as an adjective.**

"*The lawyer, tired of the trial, disappeared without explanation*"

"*El abogado, **cansado** del juicio, desapareció sin dar explicación*" (Participle)

Some verbs have two **participle** forms:
*loose/loose - printed/printed - confused/confused* (*soltado/suelto - imprimido/impreso - confundido/confuso*).

**8 - What we call absolute clauses.**

Examples:

"claim filed" - “**presentada** la demanda” (**Participle**)

“seen the file” - “***visto** el expediente*” (**Participle**)

“read the statements” - “***leídas** las declaraciones*” (**Participle**)

“time has elapsed” - “***transcurrido** el plazo*” (**Participle**)

**9 - Archaic use of the Latin present participle**:

Examples:

“*It follows from the background information*...” “*de los antecedentes **obrantes** se desprende.*..” (**obrante** - person who does)

"*the undersigned*" “*el abajo **firmante***” (**firmante** - person who signs)

"*Signature of the declarant*". “*firma del **declarante***”. (**declarante** - person who declares)

**10 - Use Past participle + “que” + verb**.

Example:

"*after they are*" "***transcurridos** que sean*"

**11 - Use and abuse of** "**queísmo**".

Omission of the conjunction "**que**", admitted by the RAE but inadvisable.

Examples:

“*I beg you to answer quickly” - “I beg you (to) answer quickly*” “*le ruego conteste con brevedad” - “le ruego (**que**) conteste con brevedad*”.

“*requests to be reviewed” - “requests (that) it be reviewed*”. “*solicita sea revisado*” - “*solicita (**que**) sea revisado*”.

“*I have agreed to proceed with the opening of the file*” - “*agreed (that) the proceeding with the opening of the file*”. “*he acordado se proceda a la apertura de expediente*” - “ *acordado (**que**) se proceda a la apertura de expediente*”.

“*wish to be taken into account” - “wish (to) be taken into account*. “*desea se le tenga en cuenta” - “desea (**que**) se le tenga en cuenta*”.

**12 - Absence and abuse of Concordance**

Between subject and verb
Between pronouns
In constructions with participles
Between noun and adjective
Between noun and relative
Between article and name

In general, these are some examples of legal language and its use.

---

Comment: I find your answer extremely confusing. Why don't you clearly label the tenses and bold them and put the sentences underneath.

Comment: Gracias Lambie. He intentado reformarlo de nuevo a ver si de esta manera parece menos confuso. Aunque el lenguaje jurídico no son solo los tiempos verbales, el resumen del subjuntivo se encuentra en el número 3, por si es este el que más específicamente se va buscando. Si consideras que hay que cambiar algo, estímalo como tal.

Comment: Esta respuesta está enteramente extraída/copy-paste de [este artículo/PDF](http://www5.poderjudicial.es/secp10-11/Documentaci%C3%B3n%20Espa%C3%B1ol/DOSSIER%201%20TEORIA/El%20espa%C3%B1ol%20jur%C3%ADdico%20-La%20gram%C3%A1tica.pdf) y carece de referencia al enlace original.

Comment: I will read the answer now, but I was just looking for a simple example, it is why I said La Isla de StackExchange donde tengo que crear mis propios leys usando el futuro del subjuntivo :-p.

Comment: Examples of the subjunctive can be found in number (3 - Some aspects of the use of the Subjunctive (With actions considered doubtful or unreal and actions considered necessary or desired.)